# GPU Processing in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, gpgpu, gpu

I've got a program that takes about 24 hours to run. It's all written in VB.net and it's about 2000 lines long. It's already multi-threaded and this works perfectly (after some sweat and tears). I typically run the processes with 10 threads but I'd like to increase that to reduce processing time, which is where using the GPU comes into it. I've search google for everything related that I can think of to find some info but no luck.

What I'm hoping for is a basic example of a vb.net project that does some general operations then sends some threads to the GPU for processing. Ideally I don't want to have to pay for it. So something like:

```
'Do some initial processing eg.
dim x as integer
dim y as integer
dim z as integer
x=int(textbox1.text)
y=int(textbox2.text)
z=x*y
'Do some multi-threaded operations on the gpu eg.
'show some output to the user once this has finished.
```

Any help or links will be much appreciated. I've read plenty of articles about it in c++ and other languages but I'm rubbish at understanding other languages!

Thanks all!

Fraser

Comment: Wait, you have a 10-core computer? I doubt that. More threads only make sense if you have enough processors.

Comment: Konrad: Your right 10 threads isn't the optimum number. I'm guessing for me that's about 7 or 8. But from a organisational point of view it makes my life much easier to do it in batches of 10. ANy ideas on using the GPU?

Comment: It may make your life easier but it also makes the code much (!!!) slower. On using the GPU: I doubt there’s a solution for VB. Mono has some SIMD modules in its core library but nothing for general-purpose GPU programming since it’s normally easier to just load a C++ library which implements the GPU logic. Having native GPU programming in VB doesn’t gain you anything, and the abstraction of the GPU doesn’t mix well with the .NET framework design.

Comment: I just assumed that there must be a way to use a GPU in vb.net as it seems you can do so in other languages. For what I'm running I expect it would make a huge speed increase as what my code does is essentially just maths relating to geometry - which is pretty much what a GPU is designed to do. I did toy with the idea of learning c++ and slowly transferring my code over from vb.net. The issue with this is my vb.net knowledge is pretty good now and if I start using C++ I'd be starting over. I'm still hoping there's a way, any ideas?

Comment: Other languages which “support” using the GPU need a special compiler. For instance, C++ doesn’t actually support GPGPU programming. If you want to do GPGPU programming in C++ using CUDA, you’re actually using a different compiler (nvcc) to compile your GPU code.

Comment: So, to confirm I understand: When you write GPGPU code in C++ it's compiled with NVCC? Can't I just write the GPGPU code and use that compiler with vb.net then or does that compiler only work with c++ code? I was hoping to find a work around that would allow me to 'send' some code to be executed in the GPU. So the code would execute in GPU from line x to line y. It sounds like my best option might be to learn c++ then?

Comment: Well, the nvcc compiler obviously needs to know how to parse the source language and it expectes (a limited subset of) C++ as the source language.

Comment: OK I'm making this question as answered. I have asked another related question, please check it out I'm sure you'll be able to help! Thanks!

Comment: Wow, good find with Cudaify. I was apparently wrong then. Strong stuff. Best of luck with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The VB.NET compiler does not compile onto the GPU, it compiles down to an intermediate language (IL) that is then just-in-time compiled (JITed) for the target architecture at runtime. Currently only x86, x64 and ARM targets are supported. CUDAfy (see below) takes the IL and translates it into CUDA C code. In turn this is compiled with NVCC to generate code that the GPU can execute. Note that this means that you are limited to NVidia GPUs as CUDA is not supported on AMD.

There are other projects that have taken the same approach, for example a Python to CUDA translator in [Copperhead](https://developer.nvidia.com/content/copperhead-data-parallel-python).

[CUDAfy](http://cudafy.codeplex.com/) - A wrapper on top of the CUDA APIs with additional libraries for FFTs etc. There is also a [commercial version](http://www.hybriddsp.com/Products.aspx). This does actually

> CUDAfy Translator
>   Using SharpDevelop's decompiler ILSpy as basis the translator converts .NET code to CUDA C.

There are other projects to allow you to use GPUs from .NET languages. For example:

[NMath](http://www.centerspace.net/blog/nmath-premium/announcing-nmath-premium-gpu-accelerated-math-libraries-for-net/) - A set of math libraries that can be used from .NET and are GPU enabled.

There may be others but these seem to be the main ones. If you decide to use CUDAfy then you will still need to invest some time in understanding enough of CUDA and how GPUs work to port your algorithm to fit the GPU data-parallel model. Unless it is something that can be done out of the box with one of the math libraries.

It's important to realize that there is still a performance hit for accessing the GPU from a .NET language. You must pay a cost for moving (marshaling) data from the .NET managed runtime into the native runtime. The overhead here largely depends on not only the size but also the type of data and if it can be marshaled without conversion. This is in addition to the cost of moving data from the CPU to the GPU etc.

Comment: Wow. You answered a question from almost a year ago. What you've suggested is what I've already done, and as you mentioned the data transfer to/from the gpu was significant - to the extent that it became slower than the previous code. Thanks for the answer!